# How to create custom sessions on Google App Engine using Cloud Endpoints?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session, google-cloud-endpoints, webapp2

I am creating a website where there need to be 2 options for Login.

Login form is made in html/angular js.

I have a Login API as the backend (as google cloud endpoint which can take 2 mechanism for auth process mentioned below)
This Login api will authenticate user based either of the 2 things mentioned below

1. Using Google Signin (OAuth2). This thing is pretty simple to figure out in backend for which email id is logged in using `endpoints.get_current_user()`
2. Using custom authentication with username and password.

**My problem:** How to create session if user logs in using second option i.e using custom authentication with username and password.

I tried out webapp2 extras for session but nothing worked out.

Is there any way to have sessions storage if i am using google cloud endpoints. ???

I am working with python.

**PS: if there's a hack, i don't want to use cookies. Please suggest some other option.**

Comment: Please edit your question and place the requirements in it, comments can easily be missed.

Comment: Thanks Dan, i have updated my question.